# Literature on identifiability of multiple seasonality

Tags: time-series, seasonality, multiple-seasonalities

A straightforward interpretation of identifiability of seasonal patterns as an ability of a method to extract seasonal pattern or patterns correctly from an artificially created signal does not appear to work well. To illustrate this, let us consider a time series, artificially created, which has two seasonal patterns with periods two and four, and where the pattern for seasonality with period four repeats twice the seasonal pattern with period two. Obviously, a combination of these two patterns with fractions $0<\alpha<1$ and $1-\alpha$ will get exactly the same signal and no method will be able to guess correctly $\alpha$ better than by chance. A similar illustration can be created for a pair of seasonal patterns with periods which are whole numbers and one is not a multiple of another (for example three and five). Thus, the identifiability issue can be further investigated only for some subclasses of seasonal patterns.
The following proposition looks rather obvious:

Proposition:

Assuming there is no trend, multiple seasonal patterns can be identified if, and only if, they have no common frequencies in their Fourier representation.

The question: Is there any literature, which investigates this any further?